# Qt creator cannot find dependent library when running the app

Tags: c++, qt

I have a Qt application project which depends on another Qt library project. I have following in my application pro file to include library.

```
win32:CONFIG(release, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../CommonLibs/build/Debug/MyLib/release/ -lMyLib
else:win32:CONFIG(debug, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../CommonLibs/build/Debug/MyLib/debug/ -lMyLib
else:unix: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../CommonLibs/build/Debug/MyLib/ -lMyLib

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../CommonLibs/MyLib
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../CommonLibs/MyLib
```

Until today, my application successfully compiled and I could run, debug the application through QtCreator. But suddenly, even though I can compile the application, I cannot run it through QtCreator. When I try to run it, QtCreator reports that application exited but if I put a breakpoint in `main()`, it doesn't get hit.

If I manually copy the dependent library dll file to the directory where application exe exists, then I can run it through QtCreator.

I checked the build environment project setting in QtCreator and my lib path exists in the `PATH` variable.

I cannot remember any significant action I did which could have created this issue.

Can anyone give me a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with another library which the library mentioned in the question depends on. I have newly created this library and made the previously mentioned library depend on it.

To be able to run the application, I had to add a dependency of this new library to my application `.pro` file. Then, all worked fine.